# Regular Expressions - match a string containing "+" and "-"

Tags: java, regex, string, numbers, number-formatting

I have a string, say `1+++-3--+++++2` that includes `+` and `-` sign.
What I want to do is to represent the `+` and `-` part with `+` or `-` sign.
If there are an odd number of `-` sign in the string, I will replace it with `-`, and `+` if that is an even number. How can I do that using regex?

For example, I have a math expression, say `1+-+-2-+--+3`. It will be replaced by `1+2-3`

Comment: you might wanna go into more details. if both `-` and `+` are odd/even what happens? if `-` is odd and `+` is even what happens?

Comment: I don't care about the number of `+` are odd or even, the final result is only affected by the number of `-`

Comment: doesn't really sound like a regex problem

Comment: as I've said, I use regex to match a string containing `+` and `-` sign

Comment: How are you expecting 1+-+-2-+--+3 to be 1+2-3?

Comment: if you have a Casio calculator, you you see that **1+-+-2-+--+3 = 1+2-3 = 0** :)

Comment: but you just said it includes only `+` and `-`, and now you're including other character sets? What is it that you really want?

Comment: You could split the string at each number then process the chars in between (`+` &`-`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an array of the operators and use a `for` loop to count all occurrences of one character. For example:

```
String expression = "1+++-3--+++++2";
String[] str = expression.split("[0-9]+");

for(op : str) {
    int count = 0;
    for(int i =0; i < str.length(); i++)
        if(op.charAt(i) == '-')
            count++;

    if(count % 2 == 0) {
        op = "-";
    }
    else {
        op = "+";
    }
}
```

After assigning the modified one-character operators in `str[]`, it should be relatively simple to write the new expression.

Comment: what if the string is `1++++--++3---+++---4`?

Comment: @DizzyCode You need to add in an `else` statement to deal with the string if the number of occurrences is even

Comment: @UnknownOctopus Hmm, thanks for the suggestion, I'll see if I can improve the answer. The question seems to have changed.

Comment: @DizzyCode No problem :). Should just be a simple `}else{ str=str.replaceAll("-","+");}` Also, in your `if` statement's replaceAll you should switch `("-","+")` to `("+","-")` according to what OP wants

Comment: @UnknownOctopus I believe the question is now asking to replace the entire string with one character.

Comment: @DizzyCode Yeah, i see the edit, not too sure what OP actually wants

Comment: not the entire string, only the part containing **+** and **-** sign. Your code count all the **-** character in the string, I think that's not true

Comment: @TheDarkKnight I modified the code to deal with an expression. Weren't you asking to count if there is an odd or even number of - signs?

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I want

Answer (score 1):

based on the assumption that the format will be from that calculator example.

```
//assumed format for input: <any number><any number of `-` and/or `+`><any number>

// 1++---+22+--1 will be 1-22+1
String input = "1++---+22+--1";
for (String s : input.split("[^-+]+");) {
    s = s.trim();
    if (!"".equals(s)) {
        String newStr = s.matches("[+]*-([+]*-[+]*-)*[+]*") ? "-" : "+";
        input = input.replace(s, newStr);
    }
}
System.out.println(input);
```

Comment: Technically, you can write better code with Pattern/Matcher loop: `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[+-]+"); Matcher m = p.matcher(input); StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer(); while (m.find()) { if (m.group().matches("[+]*-([+]*-[+]*-)*[+]*") m.appendReplacement(out, "-"); else m.appendReplacement(out, "+"); } m.appendTail(out);`